# How to duplicate a class

Tags: inria-spoon

My requirement is as such: I have a class (`a.b.C1`) contained in 3rd party library which I want to duplicate so I can make modifications and result into `x.y.C2`. In a few words, I need to make `x.y.C2` inherits `a.b.C1` and strip down few methods, and change visibilities.

As I stumbled on lot of "issues" *(certainly due to my lack of knowleges on this topic)*. What I do is: create class `x.y.C2` and copy one by one fields/methods/nested types. The problem doing that, is when I copy a method having statements containing a nested type, the statement will contain references to the nested type I'm copying the nested from (`a.b.C1.N`) instead of (`x.y.C1.N`)

First, is there a way to make this more straightforward? Ideally, I'd like to duplicate the class into new package (`x.y`) and make sure nested types will references this new class

Answer (score 0):

Use the `clone()` method.

`aCtClass.clone()`

Comment: more info in the docs: [ICloneable.Clone Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icloneable.clone?view=net-8.0)